# Is it possible to use two GPUs in viewport rendered preview, and not only for final render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have two Nvidia GPUs and they work fine in normal rendering (when I press F12, both are working).

However, in viewport, when I select "Rendered" as a viewport shading mode, only one is used. Is it possible to use both of them in viewport?

Comment: Out of curiousity how do you know both aren't working in preview mode? Thanks.

Comment: because there was no noticeable speed increase in the viewport, as opposed to the final render (f12) where the increase was significant

Comment: Short answer is "Yes", see details [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10543/696). :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Open *User Preferences* and go to the *System* tab. Under *Compute Device*, select *CUDA* and multiple gpus (*should be the one with (2x)*). Next in the *Render* context, make sure that *Device* is set to *GPU*. It should now use both for rendering in the viewport.

Comment: I thought that setting controlled both the viewport and the render? Is there a separate setting for the render somewhere that I missed?

Comment: @gandalf3 hmm? I'm not sure how exactly Blender determines this at runtime as it uses both for F12 renders while it uses whatever is set to that value for rendering in the viewport (which by default is set to one, even if you have two).