# Can multiple video cards benefit to Cycles Preview?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I know that multiple video cards can speedup the final render for Cycles. Now I'm just wondering whether it is also true for Cycles **Preview** mode (i.e. the *Rendered* display mode in 3D View).

If it is, then how?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, but I don't actually have two cards to test this..

Comment: In my experience I didn't observe any speed increase in preview mode, while in final render the increase is significant (I have two cards). I even asked similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/is-it-possible-to-use-two-gpus-in-viewport-rendered-preview-and-not-only-for-fi

Comment: @jubi with the upcoming addition of OpenSubdiv we will also get a benefit of faster non-rendered drawing in the 3DView. OpenSubdiv can perform the subdivision calculations on the gpu removing a load that is currently handled by only one cpu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just got chance to receive first-hand answer from Cycles developer:

> Yes, multiple GPUs will also help in **3D View**, no extra settings or so needed. It works already.
>
> Actually, in **3D View**, it does the same as regular render (by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>)
>   if "Progressive Refine" is enabled, which renders all tiles with 1 sample, then again, all tiles with another sample.
>
> One thing should be mentioned is that although GPU got advangtages on speed, a lot of optimizations these days still are CPU only.