# Cycles Render Preview is Slower on 2 Video Cards than 1

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Got a GTX 1080 & a GTX 760. Cycles rendering in the preview (Shift + Z) is much faster in both 2.79 & 2.79.4 with only the GTX 1080. Once I enable both the GTX 1080 and the GTX 760 and use the Cycles render preview, it is quite a bit slower, but I was expecting it would be faster. Is this a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Viewport preview only ever uses one card. It is probably using the slower one when both are enabled

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am [pretty sure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/can-multiple-video-cards-benefit-to-cycles-preview) all the GPUs are utilized in viewport also. Never had a problem with this and they show utilized in GPU-Z also.

Comment: You are right, was under the impression it did not. I found this https://developer.blender.org/T44273